# How to calculate FrameLength without using AudioSystem?

Tags: android, javasound

I'm porting Java project to Android.

As you know, the Android does not have javax.sound package.

I need to calculate frameLength.

My sound file size is 283KB. And frame size is 4 and frame rate is 44100 and sample size in bits is 16.

The frame length was 69632 when I used just pure Java.

Do you know any equation to get this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

For the raw PCM data, basically, you have 4 bytes per sample.

((283 KB) * (1024 bytes per KB)) / (4 bytes per frame) ==> 72448

But a wav can include a lot besides the raw PCM, e.g., song title or artist info.

[Here's](http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html) some more info about wav format. You might have to load the file as raw bytes to parse the header, but the header has the frame size in a predictable location.

Maybe someone else with Android experience has already concocted a method.
Maybe Google should treat Java as an intact entity and properly license and implement it.