# How to get the frameLength/frameSize of an audio file in android

Tags: android, audio

I saw this:
[How to calculate FrameLength without using AudioSystem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7124709/how-to-calculate-framelength-without-using-audiosystem), but i think the calculations here is wrong in getting the framelength. so how do i get the frameLength and frameSize of an audio in android? i know that javax.sound.* arent inclusive in the android package. so is there any alternative in getting the frameLength and frameSize?